# Source code of my website is different than that shown by firebug

Tags: php

Recently one of my client website was hacked When I checked the source code of the website it was fine(No such hacking information was there),

But when I checked the same with firebug it was showing different **i.e hacked code with some iframes**,

Then I tried to use file_get_content() function to display the index page which was displayed as hacked but when I tried to check the source of the website with file_get_content() again no such hacking information was there.

In such scenrio how i can get the actual source of the webpage in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest Using

> FTP

to the source documents or find the source documents on your own server and use an editor to look for the bad code.

If you don't have FTP access or access to the source files then you need to get that access.
I use

> FileZilla FTP Client

I know this Doesn't Help In Your Question But There Could Be More Wrong With Source Files then some simple IFrames.
If you still don't see any Problems With The Source Files Then There Most Likely Isn't Anything In That File And Not Added Somewere else with:

```
include 'file.php';
```

or

```
require_once 'file.php';
```

To Use PHP `file_get_contents` please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You could run a search:

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://test.com/home.html');
if(strpos($text, "<IFrame")!==false)
{
    echo('IFrame found');
}
else {
    echo('IFrame Not found');
}
```

Or

```
if(preg_match('/^<iframe /',$text)){
    echo 'That has an iframe using Regular Expressions!!';      
}
```

If that still doesn't help then always use a backup system when done with a change back up. Restore A Back up of said site or files see if that helps.

Comment: Actually i remotely want to access the source code of index page, Which is possible either by curl or by file_get_content but both are not showing the actual source

Comment: try `var_dump($text);`

Comment: if your getting a page that looks like normal then change `header('Content-type: text/plain');` to not see page and see code. If your getting `bool(false)` your page is not being reached and is blocked or not connecting.